# Dot Net dll used by Navision unable to write file on the local drive

Tags: navision

I have a dot net dll which is being used by the Navision code.
In my scenario the dot net method in the dll queries the alfresco and writes the file bytes on a specified folder on the local machine.
In this scenario i get an error Äccess is denied.
When Navision team tries to write in a particular folder it gives an error saying that Either caller does not have sufficient permissions or the folder is read-only.

We have tried giving all the access and privileges to the service account being used by the Navision service but nothing works.

Kindly help me on this!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using RTC Client you must know that dll is probably running on the middle tire (NAV Server), and trying access to file localized on the server.

I can't tell you more without a source code.

But please look on properties of your .net variable in NAV and check parametr "RunOnClient" if it is set to "No" then variable is run on the server and you (or your NAV partner) must use this scenario:

Save file generated by your dll to temporary folder on the server and next download this file to the client location. Functions in NAV that you will need are in Codeunit 419 - File Management (NAV 2013, NAV 2013R2)